# Writing Cython extension: how to access a C struct internal data from Python?

Tags: python, c, struct, wrapper, cython

**Disclaimer:** I took the following example from the **Python Cookbook** (O'Reilly).

Let's say I have the following simple `struct`:

```
typedef struct {
  double x,y;
} Point;
```

with a function that calculates the Euclidean distance between two `Point`s:

```
extern double distance(Point* p1, Point* p2);
```

All this is part of a shared library called `points`:

- `points.h` - the header file
- `points.c` - the source file
- `libpoints.so` - the library file (the Cython extension links against it)

I have created my wrapping Python script (called `pypoints.py`):

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "points.h"


// Destructor for a Point instance
static void del_Point(PyObject* obj) {
  // ...
}

// Constructor for a Point instance
static void py_Point(PyObject* obj) {
  // ...
}

// Wrapper for the distance function
static PyObject* py_distance(PyObject* self, PyObject* arg) {
  // ...
}

// Method table
static PyMethodDef PointsMethods[] = {
  {"Point", py_Point, METH_VARARGS, "Constructor for a Point"},
  {"distance", py_distance, METH_VARARGS, "Calculate Euclidean distance between two Points"}
}

// Module description
static struct PyModuleDef pointsmodule = {
  PyModuleDef_HEAD_INIT,
  "points", // Name of the module; use "import points" to use
  "A module for working with points", // Doc string for the module
  -1,
  PointsMethods // Methods provided by the module
}
```

Note that this is just an example. For the `struct` and function above I can easily use `ctypes` or `cffi` but I want to learn how to write Cython extensions. The `setup.py` is not required here so no need to post it.

Now as you can see the constructor above allows us to do

```
import points

p1 = points.Point(1, 2)   # Calls py_Point(...)
p2 = points.Point(-3, 7)  # Calls py_Point(...)

dist = points.distance(p1, p2)
```

It works great. However what if I want to actually access the internals of the `Point` structure? For example how would I do

```
print("p1(x: " + str(p1.x) + ", y: " + str(p1.y))
```

As you know a `struct` internals can be directly accessed (if we use C++ terminology we can say that all `struct` members are `public`) so in a C code we can easily do

```
Point p1 = {.x = 1., .y = 2.};
printf("p1(x: %f, y: %f)", p1.x, p1.y)
```

In Python class members (`self.x`, `self.y`) can also be accessed without any getters and setters.

I can write functions which act as an intermediate step:

```
double x(Point* p);
double y(Point* p);
```

however I am unsure how to wrap these and how to describe their call inside the table of methods.

How can I do that? I want to have a simple `p1.x` for getting the `x` of my `Point` structure in Python.

Comment: The `double x(Point* p);` is a function declaration of a function named `x` which takes a pointer to a `Point` as an argument and returns a `double` — so you should be able to wrap (as well as write) it. Likewise for `y` function.

Comment: To use `p1.x` and `p1.y` notation Python, given a class like `Point`, you could create properties (with associated getters and possibly also setters) for an attributes named `x` and another one for `y`. Not sure if it's possible to implement properties to Cython.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was initially a little confused about this question since it seemed to have no Cython content (sorry the editing mess resulting from that confusion).

The [Python cookbook uses Cython in a very odd way](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch15.html#_discussion_248) which I wouldn't recommend following. For some reason it wants to use PyCapsules which I have never seen used before in Cython.

```
# tell Cython about what's in "points.h"
# (this does match the cookbook version)

cdef extern from "points.h"
    ctypedef struct Point:
        double x
        double y

    double distance(Point *, Point *)

# Then we describe a class that has a Point member "pt"
cdef class Py_Point:
    cdef Point pt

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.pt.x = x
        self.pt.y = y

    # define properties in the normal Python way
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.pt.x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,val):
        self.pt.x = val

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.pt.y

    @y.setter
    def y(self,val):
        self.pt.y = val

def py_distance(Py_Point a, Py_Point b):
    return distance(&a.pt,&b.pt) # get addresses of the Point members
```

You can then compile it and use it from Python as

```
from whatever_your_module_is_called import *

# create a couple of points
pt1 = Py_Point(1.3,4.5)
pt2 = Py_Point(1.5,0)

print(pt1.x, pt1.y) # access the members

print(py_distance(pt1,pt2)) # distance between the two
```

In fairness to the Python Cookbook it then gives a second example that does something very similar to what I've done (but using a slightly older property syntax from when Cython didn't support the Python-like approach). So if you'd have read a bit further you wouldn't have needed this question. But avoid mixing Cython and pycapsules - it isn't a sensible solution and I don't know why they recommended it.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. Does this mean you have to use cython and the c API is deprecated?

Comment: No - the C API is not deprecated. However if you've already taken the decision to use Cython then you may as well use it properly instead of doing a half-hearted mix of Cython and PyCapsules.